# Double integral substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am looking for a substitution which will allow me to compute the double integral, $$\iint \frac{\cos(x-y)}{\sin(x+y)}\,dA,$$ over region bound by $x+y=\frac{\pi}{2}$, $x=0$, and $y=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should let $u=x+y,\,v=x-y$. This will give

$$ x=\frac{1}{2}(u+v)\qquad y=\frac{1}{2}(u-v) $$

This will result in a Jacobian factor of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Your bounds become

\begin{eqnarray}
u&=&\frac{\pi}{2}\\
u+v&=&0\\
u-v&=&\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
So the integral becomes

$$ \frac{1}{2}\int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-u}^{u-\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos v}{\sin u}dv\,du $$

[image: region of integration]

Here's a refresher on this type of [substitution using a Jacobian](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx).